# Is it okay to have a composite key of 1 pKey and 2 attributes

Tags: c#, sql, database

I am building an ecommerce store and for each item, there are different colors and sizes. So is it fine to have a ProductType table with 3 composite keys to define a unique row joining to a Product table?

```
Product Table: 
Product ID(pKey), Category ID, ModelNumber, ModelName

ProductType Table:
Product ID(pKey), Size(pKey), Color(pKey), Quantity
```

Answer (score 1):

Having a composite primary key composed of 3 foreign keys (or more) is fine.

If the composed key uniquely identifies a row, then it is a good primary key.

Comment: Unless `Size` and `Color` are `VARCHAR(100)` which may well be the case here.

Answer (score 1):

If ProductType being used for lookup its not good use 3 composite key ,i recommend create a column for make unique the types,because type will be used in many tables and putting these 3 column in each table doesnt look good,
also u put Quantity in ProductType  ,i think it is'nt ok!

Comment: Thanks for the advice, sorry but can you please advice why Quantity isn't good to be in the ProductType?

Comment: because we can have variable Quantity for an item,and it changes during the time,but the type itself never changes